# post sending base64 image with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to generate an image out of a canvas and send it to server through a POST request made with ajax.
I'm using html2canvas to convert a div to canvas and to convert it into base64 with toDataURL().

here's my JS:

```js
  function genImg(){
    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#ogImage")).then(canvas => {
      var renderedImg = canvas.toDataURL()
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "script.php",
        data: {
          base64Img: renderedImg
        }
      }).done(function(o){
        console.log("saved")
        console.log(renderedImg);
      })
    });
  }
```

And here's my script.php file:

```
<?php
   $img = $_POST['data'];
   $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64, ', '', $img);
   $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
   $fileData = base64_decode($img);
   //saving
   $fileName = 'photo.png';
   file_put_contents($fileName, $fileData);
?>
```

Both scripts are working and a png is generated with the correct output name, but the generated png is empty.
I checked the received request and what is sent in post, both are different...
console.log(renderedImg) is a really really long base64 code.
and the request is also a base64 code but clearly shorter. Is there a limit of what can be send with POST request ? or do I forgot something ?

Also to check where my problem is, I copy/paste the javascript console.log(renderedImg) output and decoded it with https://www.base64decode.org/
the result is exactly the image i needed.
Then I tried with the POST request data and it's the same result as the generated png file, empty.

So I'm pretty sure that my problem is when the data are sent from ajax to PHP.

Comment: There may be some kind of max request body size in your PHP server that is cutting off the data URL because it's too long (not sure if PHP does this, but that is certainly configurable in many server-side languages). This is my only conclusion given that you are 100% sending the right data URL and have verified that.

Comment: `toDataURL` does not just return base64 data, it has some meta data at the start.

Comment: @Keith I tried removing the metadata at the start by using :
.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "")

Comment: I'm not a PHP user, but -> `$_POST['data'];`  doesn't look like how you get the whole body of a POST request..  have you tried -> `file_get_contents('php://input');`

Comment: If you send as binary you will reduce the request size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to do it, The problem was located in the PHP file:

```
<?php
 define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'images/');
 // previously it was $img = $_POST['data']
 $img = $_POST['imgBase64'];
 $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
 $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
 $data = base64_decode($img);
 $file = UPLOAD_DIR . 'test.png';
 $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
 //send request to ocr
 print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
?>
```

From now, my saved image is exactly the one needed

Comment: Canvas does not have a src property, that line of code does nothing.

Comment: Yes you're right, I removed it, so I don't know why but it's working...

Comment: It's working because you stripped `data:image/png;base64,` from the data.

Comment: @Musa yes, but I tried to strip `data:image/png;base64,` but it didn't work because I wasn't sending the correct data, now that I replaced `$img = $_POST['data']` by `$img = $_POST['imgBase64']` it's working and I have my expected result, thank you for trying to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Data url have the form `data:[<media type>][;base64],<data>`
You have to strip the `data:[<media type>][;base64],` part before you decode.
Also use `$_POST['base64Img']` to access the data as `base64Img` is what you used in your ajax request

Comment: Hey, 
you mean that way ?

<?php
  ....
  $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64, ', '', $img);
  $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
 ....
?>

Comment: Just `$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);`